# Google sign in fragment , android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, google-plus, google-plus-signin

Using android studio

I am trying to sign in from a fragment

Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState==null)
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment=new LoginFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == LoginFragment.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        LoginFragment fragment = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutLogin);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```

Fragment code:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

/* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

/* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
 * us from starting further intents.
 */
private boolean mIntentInProgress;

/**
 * True if the sign-in button was clicked.  When true, we know to resolve all
 * issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
 */
private boolean mSignInClicked;


public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    v.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(((MainActivity)getActivity()))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle("Login");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        if (mSignInClicked && connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(((MainActivity)getActivity()), RC_SIGN_IN);
                mIntentInProgress = true;
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 //        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

}

I getting null pointer exception when I select the email:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.rnit/com.rnit.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3447)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1291)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.rnit.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3443)
```

Line no 45 is

```
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

What is the issue here? Any help?

Comment: Hey WISHY I am facing same issue, can u please let me know how did u resolved this issue?

Comment: Hello, did you end up finding a solution to this issue? I am experiencing a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this after your mGoogleApiClient initiated

```
Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```